# How to search and list files and folders with specific pattern?

Tags: file-search

Imagine I only know a part of the name of the folder(s) or file(s), but don’t know their location(s) in the computer. I even don’t know whether they are hidden or not. How can I search and list them all?

(Say, for example I want to list all the folders and files which are having mysql as the part of their name)

Comment: `find` is your friend: on command line, type `man find`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
find / -name "*mysql*"
```

Or, to find case-insensitively:

```
find / -iname "*mysql*"
```

Only files? Then:

```
find / -type f -name "*mysql*"
```

Or just directories?

```
find / -type d -name "*mysql*"
```

Maybe you want to skip other filesystems, like those in /proc or /sys:

```
find / -xdev -name "*mysql*"
```

As @richard said in a comment, you should read the man page of find to find (pun intended) all it can do.